# How to allow a Cross-Allow Request using a async await and fetch in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to get data from the News API on my front end application. I am using async-await with the fetch API, but I keep getting an error of:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https‍://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=covid&apiKey=d69affb88e344a3da1b2a12da50f680c. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

When I try to console log each news title, that's when I get an error.

```js
// async await newsApi fn
async function getNews() {
    const response = await fetch(news_api_url)
    if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log('Success , NEWS loaded')
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data);
        return data
    } else {
        throw new Error(' Unable to fetch News API data')
    }
}
```

```js
getNews()
    .then(data => {
        data['articles'].forEach(article => {
            let newsTitle = document.createElement('div')
            let link = document.createElement('a')
            newsTitle.classList.add('ticker__item')
            link.appendChild(newsTitle)
            link.href = article.url
            newsTitle.textContent = article.title
            newsTickerEl.appendChild(link)
            titles.push(article.title)
            console.log(newsTitle);

            localStorage.setItem("titles", JSON.stringify(titles));
        });
    })
```

Comment: Only the controller of the API can resolve this. By default, you can't load data from other domains, hence the error. The exception is if the called domain outputs an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header allowing your request.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `async`/`await`. See the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and the answers to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i).

Comment: @James, that's what I thought since the News API is a fairly reputable source. I'm also fetching data from other sources using the same method and I'm having no issues.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, it is related to async-await because I think I mihgt have to insert a method or post request within the function

Comment: @TylerMorales - No, again, the SOP and CORS have nothing to do with `async`/`await`. The issue (as detailed in the linked question's answers) is that your origin isn't passlisted by the origin you're trying to fetch from, so the browser denies access to the data from JavaScript code running in your origin. You'd have the same problem if you didn't use promises at all (e.g., `XMLHttpRequest`).

Comment: @James - Why does that seem weird? GET via ajax is absolutely subject to the SOP.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yep you are of course correct I was thinking about preflights

Comment: @James - I've done that. :-D